# Rails update another DB counter field when adding record to seperate DB

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have two databases in my Rails app, Teachers and Classrooms. A classroom has_many teachers and a teacher belongs_to a classroom. For each Classroom I have a "number of teachers" field that should keep track of how many teachers are assigned to a specific classroom, and the way I want to do this is every time a new teacher is added to Teachers, the "number of teachers" counter in Classrooms is updated by 1 upon clicking the submit button. I have looked around for a while now and can't seem to find a solution to this although it seems simple. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In rails we have a concept of the counter cache you should look at the concept 
please check the link 
http://yerb.net/blog/2014/03/13/three-easy-steps-to-using-counter-caches-in-rails/

**Models**

```
class Classrooms < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teachers
end

class Teachers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :classroom, :counter_cache => true
end
```

The first thing you have to do is adding a teachers_count column to the Classroom model(classrooms table)

Then counter cache will automatically update the count when you add or delete a teacher for the classroom

Comment: You should answer with the relevant content in case the link stops working.

Comment: I am still fairly new to rails so my other question is, how does the association know that the added teacher belongs to a specific classroom? Is there a foreign key I have to setup between the models?

Comment: Yes you need to add a foreign key in the teachers table with named classroom_id if you are defining one to many relationship in the above example. Then rails will do the other works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a lot of work for something as simple as the following:

```
classroom = Classroom.find_by(id: classroom_id)
var number_of_teachers = classroom.teachers.count
```

If you have well defined your models and their relations, you don't need specific field to know the number of teachers for each classroom.

Comment: I have a table in the view that displays the count number, that is why i need the update to happen in the DB